# Avoid full file paths when importing files

Tags: java, embedded-resource

Trying to read an image into java, currently what I have to do is this:

```
Image img = new Image("file:E:/Javaworkspace/Project/src/resource/image.png");
```

However, I am not the only one going to be working on that project and this path works only in my machine. I did try

```
Image img = new Image("file:/resource/image.png")
```

but this leads to `FileNotFound`. I don't know what this thing is called in English, I hope you understand what I am trying to convey here.

EDIT:

I added the folder "resource" via Build Path now and am trying to get input stream as such:

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/image.png")));
```

Needless to say, I get a `NullPointerException`, which according to the documentation, occurs when the path doesn't exist. How can it not exist after I specifically created it via Build Path, it exists in CLASSPATH. (Yes, the file is there too or can I not simply copy it into the folder? )

Comment: Do you have a folder named "resource" in your project main directory
check this http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Answer (score 2):

Place the image inside the project folder rather than using file system to access the file. Then you can use this:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/image.png"));
```

to get the image file where ever required by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can always try user.home but then if one person updates an image or adds one it won't update for you.

```
Image img = this.getClass().getResource("/resource/image.png");
```

Probably messed up parentheses

Also make sure you have folder "resource" in right folder (most likely same folder src and out are in

Comment: Null Pointer exception, for some reason.

Comment: Sorry here.                                                                                            ' `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("./picture.jpg"));`also works with Image ;p